# Steam & Origin on Ubuntu?

Tags: games, steam

Son wants an upgraded PC for gaming. I want him to learn some useful skills other than shooting people and arguing on a headset, so my compromise would be that he must use Ubuntu so he has to learn Unix commands and do some real IT work.
Is this practical? Do Origin & Steam work fully, or would he need to set up a Windows VM? Will most other serious games work ok?
Many thanks for any advice

Comment: This type of question would be better off being asked at ubuntuforums.org. This site focuses on questions about specific technical issues.

Comment: @DKBose This is a valid question. Not all questions must be technical issues. They simply need to be objectively definable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steam supports Ubuntu, and there are many games which have been ported to run native on Linux. Electronic Arts however, does not provide native versions of their games.

Valve however, has recently announced [Steam Play](https://steamcommunity.com/games/221410#announcements/detail/1696055855739350561) which can enable playing many games which are only available for Windows, on Linux without a VM. The games you wish to play may or may not work well with this.

To play in a VM as well as on the host system, you will need a second graphics card to pass through to the VM, so games can be played with appropriate performance level. You might prefer a dual boot system instead, if this is necessary.

Comment: Steam Play only supports a couple dozen titles. The only steam game I have for Windows: Tomb Raider 2013, is not one of them. Certainly the kid will become a Ubuntu IT expert trying to get this new steam beta based on `wine` spin-off to work properly :p

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Steam Play only has officially tested with a couple dozen titles. Thousands more work as well. Nobody mentioned Tomb Raider 2013, but either way it has a native port, so there's no need for Steam Play with it.